# Advantages of FSM (Finite State Machine) over SOA?

Tags: workflow, soa, jdeveloper, bpel, fsm

Can anyone tell me if there are any significant relative advantages of using FSM (Finite State Machine) over SOA (BPEL) for designing a workflow ? or does SOA has more advantages?

Answer (score 1):

The two cannot be compared.

Finite State Machine is a general mathematical concept.

BPEL is a business process language, every instance of BPEL is a finite state machine.

Comment: Thanks @Ales actually I meant to ask which would be a better option to configure/orchestrate a workflow?